# Change a specific letter / space from a string into another one

Tags: java, string

Isn't it possible to Change a specific digit/letter or even a space in a `string` and set it to another one?

Example:

```
String test = "name1 name2 name3 name4"
```

and I want to convert it into another String so that it could look like this:

```
String test2 = "name1+name2+name3+name4"
```

So how can I tell it to set all "spaces" to a +?

Comment: Do you also want to remove the duplicate 'name4' or is that a mistake in your question?

Comment: Was a mistake, hehe :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [**`replaceAll()`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
test2=test.replaceAll("\\s","+");
```

Answer (score 4):

Try [**String.replaceAll()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
test2 = test.replaceAll("\\s","+");
```

Note :
(Regex) **\s** :  (Description) **A whitespace character, short for [ \t\n\x0b\r\f]**
and since this is a special character it is preceeded by one more `\`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`String#replaceAll("\\s", "+")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method

Comment: Can u give me a simple example on how to use it? =)

Answer (score 3):

You should look into [repalceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) in `String` class

```
test2=test1.replaceAll(" ","+");
```

Answer (score 3):

What you'll need to do is search the string for the spaces and each time you've found one replace it with a designated character.

In Java there are functions to do this for you. Such as [ReplaceAll(oldStr, newStr)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), where oldStr can accept a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) and newStr is the replacement.

```
String test = "name1 name2 name3 name4";
test = test.ReplaceAll(" ","+");
System.out.println(test);
```

The output is:

> name1+name2+name3+name4

Instead of typing a space:  " "

You may add the exact character code ([ASCII code](http://www.asciitable.com/)) you wish to replace by using:

```
Character.toString ((char) i)
```

Where `i` is the ASCII number.

So the equivalent would be:

```
test = test.ReplaceAll(Character.toString ((char) 32), Character.toString ((char) 43));
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The OP is looking for a Java solution.

Comment: Oh, I missed that tag, woops.. C# and Java are quite similar so I edited to suit

Comment: Note: replaceAll takes a regular expression for the first parameter.